# Flutter: StreamBuilder builder is returning black screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a StreamBuilder listening to the user login/out status.

When I login successfully the LandingScreen StreamBuilder returns a black screen. But if I hot restart it loads the correct Scaffold..As long as I am logged in it prints the UID. But when it comes to return the (test)Scaffold its always a black screen.

I do not understand why after the transition from logging in to here its black but when I hot restart it then loads how it should.

EDIT*** I am running this on IPhone 12 Max Emulator.

```
    class LandingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(context, listen: false);

    return StreamBuilder<CurrentUser>(
      stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, dataSnapShot) {
        print(dataSnapShot.connectionState);
        if (dataSnapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          CurrentUser user = dataSnapShot.data;
          if (user == null) return LoginScreen();
          print(user.uid);
          return SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        auth.signOut();
                      },
                      child: Text('SIGN OUT HERE'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
          // return DashboardScreen();
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('data'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the login is completing before the StreamBuilder is built?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should convert this widget to the StateFull widget!

Comment: Your comment made my day. Thank you, bro. I forgot to change it to StatefulWidget